# TF Dataset API for Image augmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am using tf Dataset API to read images and its labels. I like to do multiple image augmentations on images and increase my training data size. What i have done now is like below.

```
def flip(self, img, lbl):
  image = tf.image.flip_left_right(img)
  return image, lbl

def transpose(self, img, lbl):
  image = tf.image.transpose_image(img)
  return image, lbl

# just read and resize the image.
process_fn = lambda img, lbl: self.read_convert_image(img, lbl, self.args)
flip_fn = lambda img, lbl: self.flip(img,lbl)
transpose_fn = lambda img, lbl: self.transpose(img,lbl)

train_set = self.train_set.repeat()
train_set = train_set.shuffle(args.batch_size)
train_set = train_set.map(process_fn)

fliped_data = train_set.map(flip_fn)
transpose_data = train_set.map(transpose_fn)

train_set = train_set.concatenate(fliped_data)
train_set = train_set.concatenate(transpose_data)

train_set = train_set.batch(args.batch_size)
iterator = train_set.make_one_shot_iterator()

images, labels = iterator.get_next()
```

Is there a better way to do multiple augmentations. The problem with above approach is if i add more augmentation function , that many map and concatenate is required.

Thank You

Comment: You can stack all augmentations in one function and then call tf.map. Does this helps you?

Comment: And you don't have to concatenate. You could augment your augmentations or do a random selector, that decides which augmentation is used, if you don't want to stack.

Comment: @Lau if i stack all augmentation in one function , how will i able to keep each augment result at each step ? I like to keep flip images and transpose images for the input image. If i stack then only last output remains in the map correct ? Please help me understand.

Comment: Do you want to visual safe the images or do you just want to randomly use only one augmentation?

Comment: @Lau i want to keep both flipped and transposed images.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do augmentations yourself, without relying on Keras's `ImageDataGenerator` you can create a function like `img_aug` and then use it in your model or in the Dataset API pipeline. The code below is just a pseudocode, but it shows the idea. You define all your transformations, then you have some generic threshold above which you apply a transformation and try to apply them up to X times (in the code below it is 4)

```
def img_aug(image):
  image = distorted_image

  def h_flip():
    return tf.image.flip_left_right(distorted_image)                
  def v_flip():
    return tf.image.flip_up_down(distorted_image)

  threshold = tf.constant(0.9, dtype=tf.float32)      

  def body(i, distorted_image):
    p_order = tf.random_uniform(shape=[2], minval=0., maxval=1., dtype=tf.float32)
    distorted_image = tf.case({                                      
                               tf.greater(p_order[0], threshold): h_flip,  
                               tf.greater(p_order[1], threshold): v_flip, 
                              }
                              ,default=identity, exclusive=False)
    return (i+1, distorted_image)

  def cond(i, *args):
    return i < 4 # max number of transformations

  parallel_iterations = 1
  tf.while_loop(cond, body, [0,distorted_image], 
                parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations)
  return distorted_image
```

Comment: Thank you. But i dont think this will help in my case.For ex: i have 100 images in my tf.data. I applied flip,dataset becomes 200 and then i applied transpose dataset should be 300. Flip and transpose are two independent functions and applied separately to the same images in the input datset.
With the my code listed in the question , its possible, but its not a perfect solution. Because i have to explicitly do each step.I would like to understand whether an internal iterator with in tf.data which applies multiple functions to the same image and keeping each functions state as an output image?

Comment: You may pass an epoch number to the function, and make first epoch have original images, second only vertical flip, third horizontal flip, etc. But then you will have problem with shuffling.

In this case you would put some kind of `epoch_number%number_of_transformations` in the `tf.cond` in my function above.

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternative for Image Augmentation is using [Tensorflow implemented Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras) 
which contains easy to use [api](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)

It's looks like this

```
ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, 
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2, 
    horizontal_flip = True)
```

And you are ready to use the augmented image as much as you want.

Here is an working github code example [Conv_net_with_augmentation](https://github.com/uzl/deep_learning/blob/master/dog_vs_cat/Con_net_with_augmentation.ipynb)

Comment: Thank you. I want to go with tf.data.Dataset. Looking for similar functionality with tf.data.Dataset operations.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am looking for a way to use ImageDataGenerator with tf.data.Dataset

Comment: @DrkStr, you cannot use `ImageDataGenerator` with `tf.data.Dataset`. And even if you could, it would be very slow because `ImageDataGenerator` does not use the GPU for the data augmentation. See [here how to easily do data augmentation](https://www.wouterbulten.nl/blog/tech/data-augmentation-using-tensorflow-data-dataset/) directly using the `tf.data.Dataset` API.

Comment: @RicardoCruz The link you provided tells how to do augmentation for 1 epoch. But then we would have to write manual training loop? I wanted to use the keras fit api with Dataset api, and do aug as well. So The dataset api should behave as a generator. Is that possible?