# can't stop at a breakpoint in Keras iterator.py during augmented training

Tags: python, keras, data-generation

I created two instances of a data generator class, extended from keras Sequence class, one for training and one for validation data. However, at the level of my source code I can only see the validation generator re-iterating between each epoch. I can't see the training generator. As a result, I can't verify that the augmentation of the training data is what I intended. In these snippets of the code, aug is a dict of parameters that go to a keras ImageDataGenerator instance within my myDataGen extension of Sequence. I wouldn't normally augment the validation data, but it's how I stumbled upon this conundrum:

```
    aug = dict(fill_mode='nearest',
                        rotation_range=10,
                        zoom_range=0.3,
                        width_shift_range=0.1,
                        height_shift_range=0.1
                        )
    training_datagen = myDataGen(Xdata_train,ydata_train,**aug)
    validation_datagen = myDataGen(Xdata_test,ydata_test,**aug)

    history = model.fit(training_datagen,
                                validation_data=validation_datagen,
                                validation_batch_size=16,
                                epochs=50,
                                shuffle=False,
                                )
```

Everything works and I get great results, but I just wanted to be sure about the augmentation. So I can gather from skimming through various functions in keras that the data generator I wrote populates a lower-level tensorflow Dataset, which then iterates per epoch. I just can't see how the tensorflow Dataset is getting augmented per epoch.

Now, I've also accidentally discovered that although the fit method doesn't support generators on the validation data, it does work, and with the interesting feature which I would like to have for the training generator, that of re-reading the data from disk so that it re-augments at the level of my own source code.

Bottom line, I can see hints that the tensorflow Dataset.cache() method is presumably storing my training dataset in memory after the first epoch. Can I somehow uncache() it to force a re-read and re-augmentation, or can someone point me to how a tensorflow Dataset calls augmentation methods when it iterates?

Hmm. This thread [TF Dataset API for Image augmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044066/tf-dataset-api-for-image-augmentation) makes clear that writing augmentation methods directly in the tensorflow Dataset API is easy, but a contributor writes in the comments that you can't use keras.ImageDataGenerator on a tf.data.Dataset. But I can clearly see in the keras modules that my keras dataset is being 'adapted' into an underlying tf.data.Dataset. If this comment is true, it would explain why I don't seem to be able to break on ImageDataGenerator augmentation of my training data. But how could this possibly be true?

Answer (score 0):

My confusion came the beginner mistake of overlooking the fact that of course one cannot break at the level of the keras source code after it's been compiled onto the gpu. But what's interesting that came out of this confusion, is that you CAN write a keras generator for the validation data, AND break on it for each epoch, since it is apparently NOT compiled on to the gpu... because keras doesn't support generators for the validation data! It's just that the generator is nevertheless handled nicely with no runtime error. An obscure find, but hope it may help somebody.